# Could a frame have different vendor specific fields?

Tags: ieee-802.11, packet-analysis, vendor

I was analyzing a database of probe requests until I found the following packet which has 3 different vendor specific fields. How to interpret that ? Is it just a wrong packet ?

> `RadioTap  version=0 pad=0 len=24 present=Flags+Rate+Channel+dBm_AntSignal+RXFlags+RadiotapNS+Ext Ext=[<RadioTapExtendedPresenceMask  present=b5+b11 |>] Flags= Rate=1.0 Mbps ChannelFrequency=2452 ChannelFlags=CCK+2GHz dBm_AntSignal=-65 dBm RXFlags= notdecoded='\\xbf\x00' |<Dot11  subtype=Probe Request type=Management proto=0 FCfield= ID=0 addr1=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff (RA=DA) addr2=9e:1e:21:eb:55:c0 (TA=SA) addr3=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff (BSSID/STA) SC=56976 |<Dot11ProbeReq  |<Dot11Elt  ID=SSID len=0 info='' |<Dot11EltRates  ID=Supported Rates len=4 rates=[1.0 Mbps, 2.0 Mbps, 5.5 Mbps, 11.0 Mbps] |<Dot11EltRates  ID=Extended Supported Rates len=8 rates=[6.0 Mbps, 9.0 Mbps, 12.0 Mbps, 18.0 Mbps, 24.0 Mbps, 36.0 Mbps, 48.0 Mbps, 54.0 Mbps] |<Dot11EltDSSSet  ID=DSSS Set len=1 channel=9 |<Dot11EltHTCapabilities  ID=HT Capabilities len=26 L_SIG_TXOP_Protection=0 Forty_Mhz_Intolerant=1 PSMP=0 DSSS_CCK=0 Max_A_MSDU=3839 o Delayed_BlockAck=0 Rx_STBC=0 Tx_STBC=0 Short_GI_40Mhz=0 Short_GI_20Mhz=1 Green_Field=0 SM_Power_Save=disabled Supported_Channel_Width=20Mhz LDPC_Coding_Capability=1 res1=0 Min_MPDCU_Start_Spacing=6 Max_A_MPDU_Length_Exponent=3 res2=0 TX_Unequal_Modulation=0 TX_Max_Spatial_Streams=0 TX_RX_MCS_Set_Not_Equal=0 TX_MCS_Set_Defined=0 res3=0 RX_Highest_Supported_Data_Rate=0 res4=0 RX_MSC_Bitmask=255 res5=0 RD_Responder=0 HTC_HT_Support=0 MCS_Feedback=0 res6=0 PCO_Transition_Time=0 PCO=0 res7=0 Channel_Estimation_Capability=0 CSI_max_n_Rows_Beamformer_Supported=0 Compressed_Steering_n_Beamformer_Antennas_Supported=0 Noncompressed_Steering_n_Beamformer_Antennas_Supported=0 CSI_n_Beamformer_Antennas_Supported=0 Minimal_Grouping=0 Explicit_Compressed_Beamforming_Feedback=0 Explicit_Noncompressed_Beamforming_Feedback=0 Explicit_Transmit_Beamforming_CSI_Feedback=0 Explicit_Compressed_Steering=0 Explicit_Noncompressed_Steering=0 Explicit_CSI_Transmit_Beamforming=0 Calibration=0 Implicit_Trasmit_Beamforming=0 Transmit_NDP=0 Receive_NDP=0 Transmit_Staggered_Sounding=0 Receive_Staggered_Sounding=0 Implicit_Transmit_Beamforming_Receiving=0 ASEL= |<Dot11Elt  ID=Extendend Capabilities len=8 info='\x00\x00\x08\\x84\x00\x00\x00@' |<Dot11Elt  ID=Interworking len=7 info='\x0f\\xff\\xff\\xff\\xff\\xff\\xff' |<Dot11Elt  ID=255 len=28 info='#\x01\x08\x08\x00\x00\\x80\x000\x02\x00\r\x00\\x9f\x00\x00\x00\x00\\xfd\\xff\\xfd\\xff9\x1c\\xc7q\x1c\x07' |<Dot11EltVendorSpecific  ID=Vendor Specific len=11 oui=Apple, Inc. (00:17:f2) info='\n\x00\x01\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00' |<Dot11EltVendorSpecific  ID=Vendor Specific len=7 oui=Microsoft Corp. (00:50:f2) info='\x08\x00\x11\x00' |<Dot11EltVendorSpecific  ID=Vendor Specific len=9 oui=Broadcom (00:10:18) info='\x02\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00' |>>>>>>>>>>>>>>`

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

What you point out as *3 different vendor specific fields* are parts of the MAC address fields - there are actually four of those in an 802.11 frame: destination, source, receiver and transmitter address.

Each MAC address consists of an *Organizationally Unique Identifier* (OUI) that is assigned to a vendor by IEEE-SA, and a *vendor-specific/unique identifier* which is indicated in your quote.

Comment: Thank you for your return. The only MAC addresses I can see in this frame are addr1 (broadcast), addr2 (9e:1e:21:eb:55:c0), and addr3 (broadcast). None of them belong to Apple, Inc. (00:17:f2), Microsoft Corp. (00:50:f2), or Broadcom (00:10:18). Am I missing something?